# use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compilation

I've the following error:

```
'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code.
```

How can I add this option to my makefile? This is my makefile: (I think that this option should be in the first lines of the makefile)

```
NATIVE = $(shell uname --machine)
BOARD ?= $(NATIVE)
V2XATK ?= 0
V2XLLC ?= 1
V2XQTI ?= 0

APP = obu-hmi-cohda

# Versioning
APPVERSION := 2.4.0.RC3 (2021-10-19)

# Comment/uncomment the following line to disable/enable debugging
DEBUG := y
ifeq ($(DEBUG),y)
  # "-O" is needed to expand inlines
  EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O -ggdb -DDEBUG -DDEBUG_PRINT_TIMES
else
  EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O2
endif

#Modificato puntamento a librerie compilate per x86 --> per compilazione x86

STACKDIR := $(realpath /home/duser/mk5/stack)
#STACKDIR := $(realpath /home/duser/x86/stack)
SRCDIR := $(realpath $(CURDIR))
OUTDIR := $(realpath $(CURDIR))/$(BOARD)

#############################################################################
# Import board configuration
#############################################################################

-include $(STACKDIR)/boards/$(BOARD).mk

#############################################################################
# Defaults for security libraries
#############################################################################

ifneq ($(NO_VIICSEC),1)
  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1 \
                 libmisbehaviorReport.so libmisbehaviorReport.so.1 \
                 libssl.so libssl.so.1.1 libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -lviicsec -lmisbehaviorReport -lssl -lcrypto

  ifeq ($(NO_LIBC2X),0)
    SEC_V2XLIBS += libc2x.so libc2x.so.1 libc2x.so.1.0 libc2x-compat.so libc2x-compat.so.1 \
                   libNxDispatcher.so libNxDispatcher.so.1.9 libNxDispatcher.so.1.9.3
    SEC_LDLIBS  += -lc2x -lNxDispatcher
  endif
  ifeq ($(NO_LIBV2XCRYPTO),0)
    SEC_V2XLIBS += libv2xCrypto.so libv2xCrypto.so.2.7 libv2xCrypto.so.2.7.1 \
                   libv2xCryptoPal.so libv2xCryptoPal.so.2.7 libv2xCryptoPal.so.2.7.1 \
                   libNxDispatcher.so libNxDispatcher.so.1.9 libNxDispatcher.so.1.9.3
    SEC_LDLIBS  += -lv2xCrypto -lv2xCryptoPal -lNxDispatcher
  endif
  ifeq ($(NO_AEROLINK_SCMS),0)
    SEC_V2XLIBS += libaerolinkSCMS.so
    SEC_LDLIBS  += -laerolinkSCMS
  endif
else
  SEC_V2XLIBS :=
  SEC_LDLIBS  :=
endif

#############################################################################
# BOARD specific setup
# - Folder locations, CROSSCOMPILE, CCOPTS, INSTALLDIR etc.
#############################################################################
# Allow ccache to be disabled for static analysis
CCACHE ?= ccache

ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),mk5 flowradar bach pateo ubxp3))
  # MK5 etc.
  ARCH := arm
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) arm-linux-gnueabihf-"
  INSTALLDIR ?= $(STACKDIR)/../bsp/image/rootfs

  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1 \
                 libmisbehaviorReport.so libmisbehaviorReport.so.1 \
                 libaerolinkSCMS.so libssl.so libssl.so.1.1 libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1 \
                 libc2x.so libc2x.so.1 libc2x.so.1.0 \
                 libNxDispatcher.so libNxDispatcher.so.1.9 libNxDispatcher.so.1.9.3
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -lviicsec -laerolinkSCMS -lssl -lcrypto -lc2x -Wl,--no-as-needed -lNxDispatcher -ldl

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),re2l))
  ARCH := arm
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= ccache arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  INSTALLDIR ?= $(STACKDIR)/../bsp/image/rootfs
  #SDKDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/../../../bsp/atk/craton2-sdk # TODO

  CCOPTS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon --sysroot=/opt/imx-v2x/4.1.15-2.1.0/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
  #CFLAGS += -I$(SDKDIR)/include
  CFLAGS += -I/opt/imx-v2x/4.1.15-2.1.0/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include
  #LDFLAGS += -L$(SDKDIR)/sdk/local_linux_u/lib/ --sysroot=/opt/poky-craton2/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1 \
                 libmisbehaviorReport.so libmisbehaviorReport.so.1 \
                 libaerolinkSCMS.so libssl.so libssl.so.1.1 libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1 \
                 libc2x.so libc2x.so.1 libc2x.so.1.0 \
                 libNxDispatcher.so libNxDispatcher.so.1.9 libNxDispatcher.so.1.9.3
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -lviicsec -laerolinkSCMS -lssl -lcrypto -lc2x -Wl,--no-as-needed -lNxDispatcher -ldl

#/opt/imx-v2x/4.1.15-2.1.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc

#  SEC_V2XLIBS ?= libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1
#  SEC_LDLIBS  ?= -lviicsec -laerolinkPKI


else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),mq5))
  ARCH := arm
  QNX_BASE ?= /opt/qnx660
  CROSS_COMPILE := "$(CCACHE) arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi-"
  INSTALLDIR ?=

  CPPFLAGS += -DNO_SYSINFO
  CFLAGS += -fpic

  SEC_V2XLIBS :=
  SEC_LDLIBS  :=

  V2XATK := 0
  V2XLLC := 1

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),craton2))
  ARCH := arm
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-"
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  SDKDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/../../../bsp/atk/craton2-sdk

  CCOPTS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -mfpu=neon --sysroot=/opt/poky-craton2/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
  CFLAGS += -I$(SDKDIR)/include
  LDFLAGS += -L$(SDKDIR)/sdk/local_linux_u/lib/ --sysroot=/opt/poky-craton2/2.2.1/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

#  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1
#  SEC_LDLIBS  := -lviicsec -laerolinkPKI

  V2XATK := 1
  V2XLLC := 0

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),dg2))
  ifeq (,$(findstring atks,$(CC)))
  $(error Setup the cross compilation environment first: 'source /mnt/atks/atks_yocto_sdk/atks_env_setup.sh')
  endif
  ARCH := arm
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-"
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  SDKDIR ?= $(CURDIR)/../../../bsp/atk/craton2-sdk

  CCOPTS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -mfpu=neon
  CPPFLAGS += -DNO_VIICSEC
  CFLAGS += -I$(SDKDIR)/include
  LDFLAGS  += -L$(SDKDIR)/sdk/local_linux_u/lib/

  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 \
                 libaerolinkSCMS.so libssl.so libssl.so.1.1 libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -lviicsec \
                 -laerolinkSCMS -lssl -lcrypto

  V2XATK := 1
  V2XLLC := 0

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),qti))

  ARCH := arm64
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) aarch64-agl-linux-"
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  SDKTARGETSYSROOT ?= /opt/poky-agl/3.0.0+snapshot/sysroots/aarch64-agl-linux
  CCOPTS += -fPIC --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)
  CPPFLAGS += -DNO_VIICSEC
  CFLAGS += -I$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)/usr/include
  LDFLAGS += --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)

  SEC_V2XLIBS :=
  SEC_LDLIBS  :=

  V2XLLC := 0
  V2XQTI := 1

  CFLAGS += -I$(CURDIR)/../../../bsp/QTI/include

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),mk6c))

  ARCH := arm64
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) aarch64-linux-gnu-"
  INSTALLDIR ?= $(STACKDIR)/../bsp/image/rootfs
  CCOPTS += -fPIC
  CPPFLAGS +=

  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1 \
                 libmisbehaviorReport.so libmisbehaviorReport.so.1 \
                 libaerolinkSCMS.so \
                 libv2xCrypto.so libv2xCrypto.so.2.6 libv2xCrypto.so.2.6.0 \
                 libv2xCryptoPal.so libv2xCryptoPal.so.2.6 libv2xCryptoPal.so.2.6.0 \
                 libNxDispatcher.so libNxDispatcher.so.1.2 libNxDispatcher.so.1.2.0 \
                 libssl.so libssl.so.1.1 libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl \
                 -lviicsec \
                 -lmisbehaviorReport \
                 -laerolinkSCMS \
                 -lv2xCrypto -lv2xCryptoPal \
                 -lNxDispatcher \
                 -lssl -lcrypto

  V2XLLC := 0
  V2XQTI := 1

  CFLAGS += -I$(CURDIR)/../../../bsp/QTI/include

else ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),ir800))
  ARCH := x86_64
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) "
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra #-Werror          Rimosso gestione warning as error --> per compilazione x86

  CPPFLAGS += -DNO_VIICSEC

  SEC_V2XLIBS :=
  SEC_LDLIBS  :=

else ifneq ($(BOARD),$(NATIVE))
  # Generic non-x86
  ifneq ($(SDKTARGETSYSROOT),)
    CCOPTS += -fPIC --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)
    CFLAGS += -I$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)/usr/include
    LDFLAGS += --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)
  endif

else
  # Native (PC)
  ARCH ?= $(NATIVE)
  CROSS_COMPILE ?= "$(CCACHE) "
  INSTALLDIR ?=
  CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra #-Werror          Rimosso gestione warning as error --> per compilazione x86

  SEC_V2XLIBS := libviicsec.so libviicsec.so.1 libaerolinkPKI.so libaerolinkPKI.so.1 \
         libmisbehaviorReport.so libmisbehaviorReport.so.1 \
         libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.1.1
  SEC_LDLIBS  := -lviicsec -laerolinkPKI -lmisbehaviorReport
endif

#############################################################################
# File locations
#############################################################################
# Source directories
SRCDIRS := $(SRCDIR)/src

# Add this list to VPATH, the place $(MAKE) will look for the source files
VPATH := $(SRCDIRS)

# Matching output tree
OUTDIRS := $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OUTDIR),$(SRCDIRS))

# Include folders
INCDIRS := $(SRCDIRS) \
           $(OUTDIR)/include \
           $(OUTDIR)/include/asn1 \
           $(realpath $(STACKDIR)/../cohda/kernel/include) \
           $(realpath $(STACKDIR)/../ieee1609/kernel/include) \
       $(SRCDIR)/lib/cjson/arm/include


# Aerolink
ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),$(NATIVE) mk5 mk6c jabiru flowradar bach craton2 pateo re2l ubxp3 ctx0800))
AEROLINK_SRCDIR = $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/aerolink
AEROLINK_CONFIG = $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/default
AEROLINK_SCRIPT = $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/rc.aerolink
AEROLINK_TOOLS =  \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/certadm \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/crladm \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/acfGenerator \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/acfBuilder \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/acfInfo \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/extractSignerTlmFromEctl \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/createEtsiInitRequest \
         $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/processEtsiInitResponse
endif

# ffasn1c location/options/etc.
FFASN1DIR    = $(STACKDIR)/../tools/ffasn1c
FFASN1C      = $(FFASN1DIR)/ffasn1c
FFASN1C_OPTS = -fdefine-int-values
FFASN1PY     = $(STACKDIR)/tools/ffasn1.py
FFASN1PREFIX = RAW_
FFASN1DEF    = $(SRCDIR)/src/RAW.asn1
FFASN1OUT    = $(SRCDIR)/src/raw-asn


#############################################################################
# CPPFLAGS, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LDLIBS
#############################################################################
# If using yocto/poky toolchain, use CC in environment
ifeq (,$(TARGET_PREFIX))
  CC := $(shell echo $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc)
endif
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_$(shell echo $(BOARD) | tr a-z A-Z)
CFLAGS += -fpic -Wall -Wextra #-Werror          Rimosso gestione warning as error --> per compilazione x86
LDFLAGS += -L$(OUTDIR) \
           -L$(OUTDIR)/lib \
       -L$(SRCDIR)/lib/cjson/arm/lib \
           -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,./lib

# Generate the include folders' associated CFLAGS entry by adding '-I' before each include folder
CFLAGS += $(foreach DIR, $(INCDIRS), $(addprefix -I, $(DIR)))

ifneq ($(INSTALLDIR),)
CFLAGS += -I$(INSTALLDIR)/usr/include
LDFLAGS += -L$(INSTALLDIR)/usr/lib
endif
ifneq (,$(LIBCFG_LIB_DIR))
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBCFG_LIB_DIR)/lib/.libs
endif
ifneq (,$(GPSD_LIB_DIR))
LDFLAGS += -L$(GPSD_LIB_DIR)
endif
ifneq (,$(OPENSSL_LIB_DIR))
LDFLAGS += -L$(OPENSSL_LIB_DIR)
endif
ifneq (,$(DISPATCHER_LIB_DIR))
LDFLAGS += -L$(DISPATCHER_LIB_DIR)
endif
ifneq (,$(LIBV2XCRYPTO_LIB_DIR))
  LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBV2XCRYPTO_LIB_DIR)
endif

# Plugins
V2XLIBS += libCANUDP.so
#V2XLIBS += libDNPW.so
V2XLIBS += libEEBL.so
#V2XLIBS += libEVW.so
V2XLIBS += libFCW.so
#V2XLIBS += libGLOSA.so
#V2XLIBS += libGMLAN.so
#V2XLIBS += libHLW.so
#V2XLIBS += libICW.so
#V2XLIBS += libIHW.so
#V2XLIBS += libIVS.so
#V2XLIBS += libLCW.so
#V2XLIBS += libLTA.so
V2XLIBS += libRWW.so
#V2XLIBS += libSVA.so
#V2XLIBS += libSVW.so
#V2XLIBS += libTJA.so

# Cohda libraries (platform, network & facilities layer)
V2XLIBS += libhmi.so libtm.so
LDLIBS += -lhmi -ltm
V2XLIBS += libtc.so libta.so libJudy.a
LDLIBS += -ltc -lta -lJudy
V2XLIBS += libspatmap.so
LDLIBS += -lspatmap
V2XLIBS += libivi.so libldm.so
LDLIBS += -livi -lldm
V2XLIBS += libext.so
LDLIBS += -lext
V2XLIBS += libitsfac.so libitsasn.so libitsnet.so
LDLIBS += -litsfac -litsasn -litsnet
ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),ubxp3))
LDLIBS += -lubxp3
V2XLIBS += libubxp3.so
endif
V2XLIBS += libpos.so libubx.so
LDLIBS += -lpos -lubx
ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),ir800))
V2XLIBS += libplatsv.so libclv.so
LDLIBS += -lplatsv -lclv
else
V2XLIBS += libplat.so libclv.so
LDLIBS += -lplat -lclv
endif

V2XLIBS += libtimechange.so
V2XLIBS += libconfig.a
LDLIBS += -lconfig
V2XLIBS += libgps_static.a libpcap.a
LDLIBS += -lgps_static -lpcap
V2XLIBS += $(SEC_V2XLIBS)
LDLIBS += $(SEC_LDLIBS)
ifeq ($(V2XLLC),1)
  CPPFLAGS += -DV2XLLC
  V2XLIBS += libLLC.so
  LDLIBS += -lLLC
endif
ifeq ($(V2XATK),1)
  CPPFLAGS += -DV2XATK
  V2XLIBS += libatlklocal_linux_u.a
  LDLIBS  += -latlklocal_linux_u -ltomcrypt -ltommath
endif
ifeq ($(V2XQTI),1)
  CPPFLAGS += -DV2XQTI
  V2XLIBS += libv2x_radio.so libcv2x-kinematics.so libv2x_veh.so
  V2XLIBS += libQTIVData.so
  LDLIBS  += -lv2x_radio -lcv2x-kinematics -lv2x_veh
endif

ifeq ($(BOARD),mq5)
  LDLIBS += -lsocket -lmq -lc -lm
else
  LDLIBS += -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lstdc++ -lm
endif
LDLIBS += -l:libcjson.a

# v2x-libs are installed locally in $(OUTDIR)/lib
V2XLIBS := $(addprefix $(OUTDIR)/lib/, $(V2XLIBS))

#############################################################################
# SRCS, OBJS, DEPS, LIBS etc.
#############################################################################
# Create a list of *.c sources in SRCDIRS
SRCS = $(foreach DIR,$(SRCDIRS),$(wildcard $(DIR)/*.c))

# Define objects for all sources
OBJS = $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OUTDIR),$(SRCS:.c=.o))

# Define dependency files for all objects
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

#############################################################################
# Rule generation function
#############################################################################
define GenerateRules

$(1)/%.o: %.c $(1)/%.d
    @mkdir -p $$(@D) # Create the required OUTDIR.. folder
    @# Generate dependency information as a side-effect of compilation, not instead of compilation.
    @# -MMD omits system headers from the generated dependencies: if you prefer to preserve system headers as prerequisites, use -MD.
    $$(CC) \
     -MT $$@ -MMD -MP -MF $(1)/$$*.Td \
     $$(CCOPTS) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS) $$(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@
    @# First rename the generated temporary dependency file to the real dependency file.
    @# We do this in a separate step so that failures during the compilation won’t leave a corrupted dependency file.
    mv -f $(1)/$$*.Td $(1)/$$*.d
    @# Second touch the object file; it’s been reported that some versions of GCC may leave the object file older than the dependency file, which causes unnecessary rebuilds.
    touch $$@

# Create a pattern rule with an empty recipe, so that make won’t fail if the dependency file doesn’t yet exist.
$(1)/%.d: ;
# Mark the dependency files precious to make, so they won’t be automatically deleted as intermediate files.
.PRECIOUS: $(1)/%.d

$(1)/%.gpp: %.c src-gen $(OUTDIR)/include
    @mkdir -p $$(@D) # Create the required OUTDIR.. folder
    $$(CC) -dD -E $$(CCOPTS) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS) $$(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@

$(1)/%.lst: %.c src-gen $(OUTDIR)/include
    @mkdir -p $$(@D) # Create the required OUTDIR.. folder
    $$(CC) -S     $$(CCOPTS) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS) $$(EXTRA_CFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@

$(1)/%.lint: %.c src-gen $(OUTDIR)/include
    @mkdir -p $$(@D) # Create the required OUTDIR.. folder
    -splint -shiftimplementation -warnposix -badflag --likelybool $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(CFLAGS) $$< | tee $$@

endef

#############################################################################
# Rules
#############################################################################

all:
    env BOARD=$(BOARD) $(MAKE) app

# Generate rules
$(foreach DIR, $(OUTDIRS), $(eval $(call GenerateRules, $(DIR))))

# Include dependencies
-include $(DEPS)

src-gen: asn-gen ## Create all generated code
.PHONY: src-gen

app: version src-gen $(OUTDIR) ## Build $(APP) binary (Append BOARD=? to specify a non-host target)
    $(MAKE) $(OUTDIR)/$(APP) aerolink

cpp: $(DEPS:.d=.gpp) ## Preprocess all $(APP) sources (Append BOARD=? to specify a non-host target)

lst: $(DEPS:.d=.lst) ## Generate assembler listings for all $(APP) sources (Append BOARD=? to specify a non-host target)

lint: $(DEPS:.d=.lint) ## Generate assembler listings for all $(APP) sources (Append BOARD=? to specify a non-host target)

.PHONY: all app cpp list lint

# Aerolink rule/targets
aerolink: $(V2XLIBS) $(AEROLINK_SCRIPT) $(AEROLINK_TOOLS) $(AEROLINK_CONFIG)

$(AEROLINK_CONFIG) : $(AEROLINK_SRCDIR)/config
    @mkdir -p $@
    @rsync -q -av --exclude="*.svn" $</* $@

$(AEROLINK_SCRIPT) : $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/% : $(AEROLINK_SRCDIR)/%
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @cp $< $@

$(AEROLINK_TOOLS) : $(OUTDIR)/aerolink/% : $(AEROLINK_SRCDIR)/$(BOARD)/%
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @cp $< $@

.PHONY: aerolink

# ffasn1c rules
$(FFASN1DEF):
    @ls $(FFASN1DEF) # Nothing to do

$(FFASN1OUT).c: $(OUTDIR) $(FFASN1DEF)
    -$(MAKE) --directory $(FFASN1DIR)
    $(FFASN1C) $(FFASN1C_OPTS) -fprefix=$(FFASN1PREFIX) -o $(FFASN1OUT).junk $(FFASN1DEF)
    $(FFASN1PY)                -fprefix=$(FFASN1PREFIX)    $(FFASN1OUT).junk $(FFASN1DEF)
    # Since we're linking against itsasn, we don't need to create a link to (and complile) the asn.1 codec files
    #@mkdir -p $(SRCDIR)/src/libffasn1
    #ln -sf $(FFASN1DIR)/src/libffasn1/*.[ch] $(SRCDIR)/libffasn1

asn-gen: $(FFASN1OUT).c ## Create all ASN.1 generated code
.PHONY: asn-gen

# v2x-lib targets
$(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/include $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/lib/$(BOARD):
    # Build the v2x-libs via the $(STACKDIR)'s makefile
    if [ -e $(STACKDIR)/Makefile ]; then \
      $(MAKE) -C $(STACKDIR) BOARD=$(BOARD) lib-package; \
    fi;

$(subst $(OUTDIR)/lib,$(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/lib/$(BOARD),$(V2XLIBS)): $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/lib/$(BOARD)

$(OUTDIR)/include: $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/include $(OUTDIR)
    @mkdir -p $@
    @cp -ar $</* $@/

$(V2XLIBS): $(OUTDIR)/lib/%: $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/lib/$(BOARD)/% $(OUTDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @# The referenced lib*.so library may not exist due to licensing constraints
    @if [ -e $< ]; then \
      cp -a $< $@ ;\
    fi;


# Build the application
$(OUTDIR)/$(APP): $(OUTDIR)/include $(V2XLIBS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
ifeq ($(BOARD),mq5)
    # The QNX linker assumes the presence of '-fpic' means we want a shared library rather than an executable
    $(CC) $(filter-out -fpic,$(CCOPTS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)) -o $@
else
    $(CC)                    $(CCOPTS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDLIBS)  -o $@
endif

$(OUTDIR): # Create a per-target $(OUTDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)
    @ln -sf $(SRCDIR)/* $(OUTDIR)/ # Link the contents of $(SRCDIR) en-mass to $(OUTDIR)
    @rm -f $(OUTDIR)/$(BOARD) # No circular references allowed
    @rm -f $(OUTDIR)/Makefile # A makefile in $(OUTDIR) is just confusing
    @rm -f $(OUTDIR)/src && mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)/src # Remove the link to src/ and make our own (for build artefacts)

version: $(OUTDIR)
    touch $(OUTDIR)/$@
    echo '$(APPVERSION)' > $(OUTDIR)/$@

.PHONY: version

DESTDIR:=$(shell mktemp -d)

# Note the lack of folder prefixes below. TOSHIP files are sourced from $(CURDIR) *and* $(BOARD)
TOSHIP = $(APP) \
         rc.$(APP) \
         board.conf \
         obu.cfg obu.conf \
         rsu.cfg rsu.conf \
         ui \
         lib \
         aerolink \
         post_install \
         version

board.conf:
    rm -rf board.conf && ln -s $(BOARD).conf board.conf

tarball: app board.conf ## Create a $(APP) tarball. Use `BOARD`-tarball to generate for other targets (e.g. mk5-tarball)
    @rm -f $(APP)-$(BOARD)-*.tgz
    @rm -rf $(DESTDIR)
    @mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)/$(APP)
    @cd $(CURDIR) && rsync -avRL \
      --exclude="*src*" --exclude="lib*.a" --ignore-missing-args \
      $(TOSHIP) $(DESTDIR)/$(APP) 2>/dev/null || true
    @cd $(OUTDIR) && rsync -avRL \
      --exclude="*src*" --exclude="lib*.a" --ignore-missing-args \
      $(TOSHIP) $(DESTDIR)/$(APP) 2>/dev/null || true
    @sudo chown -R root:root $(DESTDIR)
    @tar -C $(DESTDIR) \
      --exclude-vcs -czf $(CURDIR)/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz ./
    @sudo chown $(USER):$(USER) $(CURDIR)/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz
    @sudo rm -rf $(DESTDIR)
    @echo "== tarball =="
    @du -h $(realpath $(CURDIR))/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz
    @echo "== installer =="
    @base64 $(CURDIR)/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz | cat installer_header.sh - > $(CURDIR)/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-installer.sh
    @chmod +x $(CURDIR)/build/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-installer.sh

%-tarball:
    env BOARD=$* $(MAKE) tarball

.PHONY: tarball,%-tarball

install: $(BOARD)-tarball ## Install $(NATIVE) $(APP) to $(INSTALLDIR)/opt/cohda/application
    sudo install -d $(INSTALLDIR)/opt/cohda/application
ifneq (,$(findstring $(BOARD),mq5))
    # QNX's buildfile doesn't seem to support globbing so temporarily remove the version number when installing
    @mv -f $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD).tgz
    sudo install -c $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD).tgz $(INSTALLDIR)/opt/cohda/application
    @mv -f $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD).tgz $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz
else
    sudo install -c $(CURDIR)/$(APP)-$(BOARD)-Exported.tgz $(INSTALLDIR)/opt/cohda/application
endif

.PHONY: install

# Note the 'clean's
# Use 'clean' to remove locally compiled objects (and associated executables & files)
# Use 'v2xclean' to remove the 'v2x-lib' artefacts too

v2xclean: clean
    @if [ -d "$(STACKDIR)/src" ]; then \
      echo "Cleaning v2x-lib" ; \
      rm -rf $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/include ; \
      rm -rf $(STACKDIR)/v2x-lib/lib/$(BOARD) ; \
    fi

clean: ## Clean up. Use `BOARD`-clean to specify the target (e.g. mk5-clean)
    @# Generated source(s)
    rm -f $(FFASN1OUT)*
    @# Build tree
    sudo rm -rf $(OUTDIR)
    @# Deployment files & folders
    rm -f $(APP)-$(BOARD)-*.tgz

%-clean:
    env BOARD=$* $(MAKE) clean

.PHONY: clean,%-clean

help:
    @echo -e "$$(grep -hE '^\S+:.*##' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sed -e 's/:.*##\s*/:/' -e 's/^\(.\+\):\(.*\)/\\x1b[36m\1\\x1b[m:\2/' | column -c2 -t -s :)"

.PHONY: help

#############################################################################
# $(BOARD) specific rules
#############################################################################

$(NATIVE):
    env BOARD=$@ $(MAKE) app

mk5:
    env BOARD=$@ $(MAKE) app

mk6c:
    env BOARD=$@ $(MAKE) app

mq5:
    env BOARD=$@ $(MAKE) app

.PHONY: $(NATIVE)
.PHONY: mk5
.PHONY: mk6c
.PHONY: mq5
```

Comment: Maybe update your version of gcc to something recent? Then this problem will go away (as per verison 5.0.0).

Comment: You don't get to remove information from your question just because you got an answer.  This site is meant to also help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line:

```
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_$(shell echo $(BOARD) | tr a-z A-Z)
```

You can add it to the end of this line so it reads:

```
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_$(shell echo $(BOARD) | tr a-z A-Z) -std=c99
```

Comment: Although the root of the problem isn't the make file, but that a too old version of the compiler is used.